# Removing array brackets in php - AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to remove the array brackets when I call my query from my database and display it but i'm getting the results below:

- ["title1"]
- ["title2"]
- ["title3"]

I need it to display like the following below:

- title1
- title2
- title3

I thought adding [json-encode.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) would fix this problem, but it's not. What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

**Javascript (Ajax request)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get.php',
        }).done(function(data){
            $('.right ul').append('<li>'+ data +'</li>');
        });
});
```

**PHP** (get.php)

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "adminn";
$pass = "1234";
$db = "admin";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM sample_table WHERE username = 'admin' ");

// $data = str_replace(array("[\'","'\]"),'',$data);
foreach($query as $data)
{
    echo '<li>' . json_encode(array_values($data)) . '</li>';
}
?>
```

### SOLVED!

 
I replaced

```
`'<li>' . json_encode(array_values($data)) . '</li>';`
```

with 
    `'<li>' . $data['title'] . '</li>';`

Comment: what does the db have inside?

Comment: You are missing `dataType: "json"` in your AJAX call and loop `data`  since it is an array of values. `.done()` does not auto-magically loop the data and apply your anonymous function to each item.

Comment: If you're calling that PHP file via Ajax you'll either want to output a JSON and parse that with your JS Ajax request - or change your Ajax request so that it just grabs output from the PHP and appends it to your UL.

Comment: One other issue is that you're returning `<li>some stuff</li>` and appending `<li> data </li>` which becomes `<li><li>some stuff</li></li>`

Comment: You must not encode `array_values($data)` but `$data['title']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get.php',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i,v) {
                $('.right ul').append("<li>"+v+"</li>");
            });
        });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "adminn";
$pass = "1234";
$db = "admin";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT title FROM sample_table WHERE username = 'admin'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    $response = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($response, $row['title']);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

You need to explicitly state the data type in your ajax call for a start. Also I have noticed you're parsing the reponse incorrectly and have changed it above.

Comment: `array_push($data)`??

Comment: Hey @JohnBell thanks for this. I tried but no luck! The answer was simple (too simple) - I removed encode array_values($data) and just used $data['title']

Comment: What error did you receive? There's other problems with your code that aren't fixed with that solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problems are here:

```
echo '<li>' . json_encode(array_values($data)) . '</li>';
```

The query is: `SELECT DISTINCT title FROM sample_table WHERE username = 'admin'`.

Each row returned by the query is a PHP [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) that contains a single value under the key `title`. This is what you want to print. Access the value using the [square brackets syntax for arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing): `$data['title']`.

It doesn't make any sense to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to put the data in a web page. Dynamic data that is used to generate HTML must be properly encoded as HTML using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Your code should be:

```
foreach($query as $data)
{
    echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($data['title']) . '</li>';
}
```